# LogicApp - Choose ApiConnection dynamically from Header/Body HTTP trigger or whatever

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm looking for a way to dynamically choose an ApiConnection in a "SQL GET ROWS" connector (but could be applied to any other connectors of course). As a simple example, I have this workflow:

[image]

What I want to achieve is: inside the HTTP request (in the body or as a header) I'm sending "France" => so in the end the connector 'GET ROWS from PostgreSQL table" must target an ApiConnection "P01".
If I'm sending "Germany", the connector must target an ApiConnection "P02".
And so on.

I was unable to find something that fulfill my needs. I found this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/22b83226-e7a4-4168-bd31-3547367f4959/choose-api-connection-dynamically-in-logic-app?forum=azurelogicapps but it seems your ApiConnection has to be defined in this part of the LogicApp code below:

[image]

Otherwise it won't work :( I even tried to write code below but I met an error:

```
          "postgresql_datagateway": {
            "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/', parameters('logicAppLocation'), '/managedApis/', 'postgresql')]",
            "connectionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/connections', triggerOutputs()[''headers''][''x-apiconnection-name''])]",
            "connectionName": "triggerOutputs()[''headers''][''x-apiconnection-name'']"
          },
```

Thanks in advance for your help guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is not support now.

You can give your voice to [Support Dynamic API connection in Logic app designer](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/38995327-support-dynamic-api-connection-in-logic-app-design) and vote up this feedback to prompt the feature to be achieved as soon as possible.

Comment: I was afraid it was this answer but it seems the right answer for now :( that option would be useful for many people Thank you Joey ;)